# Instantiating Interfaces

Tags: go

I am newbie in Go. One thing I don't understand is why I get compile error when I want to instantiate interfaces alone but when I use array form of that interface, then no compiler error.

```
type Flag interface {
  fmt.Stringer
}

func TestCheckRequiredFlag(t *testing.T) {
    testdata := []struct {
        st []Flag
    }{
        {
            st: []Flag{//allowed
                &StringFlag{Name: ""},
            },
        },
    }

    st := struct {
        st Flag
    }{
        st: Flag{// is not allowed
            &StringFlag{Name: ""},
        },
    }
}
```

This composite literal allocates a new struct instance with the given values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braces `{}` are used for literal values of slices, structs, arrays and maps. They are not used for interface values. If you want a literal value of an interface type, you have to use the `()` syntax, which invokes a ["type conversion"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions).

For example:

```golang
x := MyInterface(&MyStruct{})
```

`x` will be of type `MyInterface`.

To correct your code:

```golang
    st := struct {
        st Flag
    }{
        st: Flag(
            &StringFlag{Name: ""},
        ),
    }
```

You can also remove the type conversion altogether, as Go allows direct assignment to interface values, with the conversion being implicit. More explicitly, the [assignability](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) rule says (edited for clarity):

> A value x of type V is assignable to a variable of type T if T is an interface type and x implements T.

So, this code will also work:

```golang
    st := struct {
        st Flag
    }{
        st: &StringFlag{Name: ""},
    }
```

Note that in composite literals such as slices, structs and maps, the values given are considered to be *assigned* to their respective index, field or key, as if they were variables, so the assignability rules apply.

Answer (score 1):

An interface is an **abstract type** that cannot be instantiated. We can only create a concrete type that implements the interface and then create an instance of that **concrete type**. But when you use the array form of the Flag interface, you are actually creating a slice of concrete types that implement the Flag interface, which is acceptable.